# Converting .docx file to html file with same name as .docx using mammoth

Tags: python, python-2.7, file, file-handling, mammoth

I have a code to convert (.doc) to HTML file. The code is:

```py
import mammoth
f=open("c: ......\\demo.docx","rb")
b=open("ABC.html","wb") 
document=mammoth.convert_to_html(f) 
b.write(document.value.encode('utf8'))
```

Now `ABC.html` will be created. Instead, I need that HTML document to be converted with same name as docx file.

Answer (score 1):

You decide which file name to use for the output file - you could just use the same name:

```
dir = 'c:\...'
filename = 'demo'
input_file = os.path.join(dir, filename + '.docx')
output_file = filename + '.html'
f = open(input_file, "rb")
b = open(output_file,"wb")
```